# SSL Certificate: how to setup CA to deal with certificate chain?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a PKI hierarchy like below.

```
root-ca ---> signing-ca ---> sub-ca-1 ---> server-cert-1  (machine 1)
                 \
                  \--------> sub-ca-2 ---> server-cert-2  (machine 2)
```

I wonder how to set up CA on each machine. For example, I create a bundle on machine 1.

```
$ cat sub-ca-1.pem signing-ca.pem root-ca.pem > cas-1.pem
```

cas-1.pem can verify server-cert-1 but it cannot verify server-cert-2. 
So if machine 1 and 2 needs mutual authentication, it will fail.

Logically, I think the right way to do is that the certificate of machine 1 (and 2) should take up to sub-ca and the CA should start from signing-ca to root-ca (like below).

```
$ cat server-cert-1.pem sub-ca-1.pem > server-1.pem
$ cat signing-ca.pem root-ca.pem > cas.pem
```

But when I verify, it fails.

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile cas.pem server-1.pem
```

I am not sure how other SSL program will verify certificate.

Anyway, in situation like this, how to set up CA and certs on each machine such that verification can pass.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Machines that verify should just need root-ca. Machines that are trying to prove their identity should have a chain of certificates from their cert up to but excluding the root-ca. The validating machine's root-ca needs to be protected from tampering, and the authenticating machines' private keys need to be kept secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be enough to either add the root-ca or the signing-ca to the CA store (e.g. the list of trusted CAs) on the client. The rest of the chain needs to be send by the server during ssl handshake, so that the client can verify the certificate up to the trusted CA.